# Parse xml ( edmx ) attribute with namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xml-parsing, edmx

I'm trying to parse the value of m:MaxDataServiceVersion from the [edmx xml](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/%24metadata) which starts like this:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
<Schema Namespace="NorthwindModel">
<EntityType Name="Category">
```

Following code returns the needed element

```
string nav = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']");
```

but all my tries to get the attribute value were not successfull. Here is what I've tried:

```
string nav = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']").GetAttribute("@{m}MaxDataServiceVersion", "");
nav = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']").GetAttribute("m:MaxDataServiceVersion", "");
nav = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']").GetAttribute("MaxDataServiceVersion", "");
nav = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']").GetAttribute("MaxDataServiceVersion", "m");
nav = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']").GetAttribute("MaxDataServiceVersion", "edmx:m");
```

Running the following code

```
XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']");
while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
    XPathNavigator navigator2 = nodes.Current.Clone();
    navigator2.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", navigator2.Name, navigator2.Value);

    while (navigator2.MoveToNextAttribute())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", navigator2.Name, navigator2.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

will output both attributes

```
m:DataServiceVersion = 1.0
m:MaxDataServiceVersion = 3.0
```

but it should be possible to get the needed one without to loop through all of them, I think...

So is there a way to get the `m:MaxDataServiceVersion` value without to loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML starts with

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"><edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
```

so one way to access the attribute of each `DataServices` element is

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
nsMgr.Add("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx");

foreach (XPathNavigator dataServices in navigator.Select("edmx:DataServices", nsMgr))
{
  string version = dataServices.GetAttribute("MaxDataServiceVersion", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
}
```

If you want the attribute value of the first such attribute then doing

```
nsMgr.Add("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
string version = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//edmx:DataServices/@m:MaxDataServiceVersion", nsMgr).Value;
```

should suffice.

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I see the schema url in chrome, firefox just hide that. Is that possible, that the url changes with time? Is there a way to determine it dynamically?

Comment: Namespace URLs are rather stable as far as I know (although I know that more of W3C owned ones like `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` or `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`). It is possible to read out namespaces at run time but I think you should ask that in a new question.

Comment: your code works, thank you. But is there any way to just skip the namespace for the attribute, similar to //*[local-name() = 'DataServices'] for the element? I mean by modifying the last line to string version = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']/@m:MaxDataServiceVersion", nsMgr).Value; I can skip the edmx NS definition.

Comment: Well `//*[local-name() = 'DataServices']/@*[local-name() = 'MaxDataServiceVersion']` should be possible but ignoring namespaces in XML that is based on namespace is in my view not a good approach. Use it at your own risk.